# Convert object array to hash map, indexed by an attribute value of the Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashmap

## Use Case

The use case is to convert an array of objects into a hash map based on string or function provided to evaluate and use as the key in the hash map and value as an object itself. A common case of using this is converting an array of objects into a hash map of objects.

## Code

The following is a small snippet in JavaScript to convert an array of objects to a hash map, indexed by the attribute value of object. You can provide a function to evaluate the key of hash map dynamically (run time).

```
function isFunction(func) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(func) === '[object Function]';
}

/**
 * This function converts an array to hash map
 * @param {String | function} key describes the key to be evaluated in each object to use as key for hashmap
 * @returns Object
 * @Example 
 *      [{id:123, name:'naveen'}, {id:345, name:"kumar"}].toHashMap("id")
 *      Returns :- Object {123: Object, 345: Object}
 *
 *      [{id:123, name:'naveen'}, {id:345, name:"kumar"}].toHashMap(function(obj){return obj.id+1})
 *      Returns :- Object {124: Object, 346: Object}
 */
Array.prototype.toHashMap = function(key) {
    var _hashMap = {}, getKey = isFunction(key)?key: function(_obj){return _obj[key];};
    this.forEach(function (obj){
        _hashMap[getKey(obj)] = obj;
    });
    return _hashMap;
};
```

You can find the gist here: [Converts Array of Objects to HashMap](https://gist.github.com/naveen-ithappu/c7cd5026f6002131c1fa).

Comment: You can use JavaScript Map instead of Object. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/54246603/5042169

Answer (score 727):

This is fairly trivial to do with [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var arr = [
    { key: 'foo', val: 'bar' },
    { key: 'hello', val: 'world' }
];

var result = arr.reduce(function(map, obj) {
    map[obj.key] = obj.val;
    return map;
}, {});

console.log(result);
// { foo:'bar', hello:'world' }
```

*Note:* `Array.prototype.reduce()` is IE9+, so if you need to support older browsers you will need to polyfill it.

Comment: Modified the usecase to avoid confusion. I tried to target scenario which is most often encountered by JS developers in view driven application.

Comment: `result = arr.reduce((map, obj) => (map[obj.key] = obj.val, map), {});`
For ES6 one-liner fans :D

Comment: @Mtz For ES6 one-line fans, mateuscb's response below is much smaller and cleaner:  `result = new Map(arr.map(obj => [obj.key, obj.val]));`.  Most importantly, it makes it super clear that a map is being returned.

Comment: @RyanShillington we are in an answer's context here, which is `Array.prototype.reduce` as proposed by jmar777. `Map` is indeed shorter but it's a different thing. I was keeping in line with the original intent. Remember this is not a forum, you might want to read more about the SO Q/A structure.

Comment: @Mtz Fair enough.

Comment: This isn't what was asked for, IMHO. The correct result for the array shown would be: `{ "foo": {key: 'foo', val: 'bar'}, "hello": {key: 'hello', val: 'world'} }`.  Note that each original element *should be kept in its entirety*. Or using the Q's data: `{"345": {id:345, name:"kumar"}, ...}`.  FIX: Change code to be `map[obj.key] = obj;`

Comment: As coded, this will return an instance of Object, not map. For instance: `result.has('foo')` will fail as `has()`  is not defined for Object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: @JacobBarnes This question was from 2014, before `Map` was a thing in JavaScript. Back then, "hash map" ~= "an object that I will shove a bunch of arbitrary properties onto".

Comment: What about `result = arr.reduce((map, obj) => ({...map, [obj.key]: obj.val}), {})`

Comment: I find these reduce calls quite clunky. What's wrong with a plain loop? `const result = {}; for (const obj of arr) result[obj.key] = obj.val;`

Comment: The result is not a map object.

Answer (score 504):

Using ES6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) ([pretty well supported](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Map)), you can try this:

```js
var arr = [
    { key: 'foo', val: 'bar' },
    { key: 'hello', val: 'world' }
];

var result = new Map(arr.map(i => [i.key, i.val]));

// When using TypeScript, need to specify type:
// var result = arr.map((i): [string, string] => [i.key, i.val])

// Unfortunately maps don't stringify well.  This is the contents in array form.
console.log("Result is: " + JSON.stringify([...result])); 
// Map {"foo" => "bar", "hello" => "world"}
```

Comment: Also important to note that to get something out of a `Map` you need to use `result.get(keyName)` as opposed to just `result[keyName]`. Also note that any object can be used as the key and not just a string.

Comment: Another **TypeScript** version would look like this: `var result = new Map(arr.map(i => [i.key, i.val] as [string, string]));` which some might find easier to understand. Note `as [string, string]` type cast added.

Comment: When I run this code in Chrome v71, I am still getting an array:
`Result is: [["foo","bar"],["hello","world"]]`

Comment: P.S. `result` is not a hash as requested by the OP.

Comment: Another typescript version: `var result = new Map<string, string>(arr.map(i => [i.key, i.val]));`

Comment: Your code helpfull for me, thanks for share @mateuscb.

Comment: I was about to comment that this didn't work in Typescript and then I saw the commented portion. LOL. Wish I could give you more than +1.

Comment: Passing an array to `Map` constructor turned out to be less performant than using `Map.set` in a loop, at least on this test: https://jsbench.me/6gkawrdlys/1

Comment: AWS SDK returns `string | undefined` in a ton of places, so Typescript version won't work with anything but static examples, because `undefined` happens a lot in the real world.

Comment: `var result = Object.fromEntries(new Map(arr.map(i => [i.key, i.val])))` if you want an Object instead of a `Map`

Comment: @AlexV that is a type assertion and should be avoided whenever possible. Instead you can type the Map using `new Map<string, string>`.

Answer (score 124):

You can use the new [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) method.

Example:

```js
const array = [
   {key: 'a', value: 'b', redundant: 'aaa'},
   {key: 'x', value: 'y', redundant: 'zzz'}
]

const hash = Object.fromEntries(
   array.map(e => [e.key, e.value])
)

console.log(hash) // {a: b, x: y}
```

Comment: This is more readable than the top answer; however, it will iterate the array twice (once for the `map` call and once for the `Object.fromEntries` call).

Comment: @knguyen yes true I guess. But in most cases I guess the extra loop won't matter

Comment: @knguyen why does it matter if it iterates twice? Are we even sure it will result in a performance hit?

Answer (score 65):

Using ES6 spread + Object.assign:

```
array = [{key: 'a', value: 'b', redundant: 'aaa'}, {key: 'x', value: 'y', redundant: 'zzz'}]

const hash = Object.assign({}, ...array.map(s => ({[s.key]: s.value})));

console.log(hash) // {a: b, x: y}
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed ;)

Comment: `const hash = Object.assign({}, ...(<{}>array.map(s => ({[s.key]: s.value}))));`
had to do this change to work with typescript.

Comment: Important to note that this method does not result with a Map but an object

Answer (score 47):

With [lodash](https://lodash.com), this can be done using [keyBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#keyBy):

```
var arr = [
    { key: 'foo', val: 'bar' },
    { key: 'hello', val: 'world' }
];

var result = _.keyBy(arr, o => o.key);

console.log(result);
// Object {foo: Object, hello: Object}
```

Comment: That is not a hashmap

Answer (score 32):

Using the spread operator:

```
const result = arr.reduce(
    (accumulator, target) => ({ ...accumulator, [target.key]: target.val }),
    {});
```

Demonstration of the code snippet on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/meap738y/).

Comment: I'm exactly here because of this! how spread operator performs agains the regular old way of just assign the new key and return the accumulator? since it's creating a new copy each time, then spread will *perform poorly*!

Comment: now you spread in every iteration.

It should be safe to mutate in reducer.

```
const result = arr.reduce(
    (accumulator, target) => { accumulator[target.key]: target.val; return accumulator },
    {});
```

Answer (score 30):

## Tersiest

```
list.reduce((obj, item) => ({...obj, [item.name]: item.value}), {})
```

```js
const list = [
  { name: 'abc', value: 123 },
  { name: 'xyz', value: 789 },
  { name: 'she', value: 'her' },
  { name: 'he', value: 'him'}
]
  
console.log(
  list.reduce((obj, item) => ({...obj, [item.name]: item.value}), {})
)
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and actual JavaScript [**Map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) instead just a JavaScript [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

```
let keyValueObjArray = [
  { key: 'key1', val: 'val1' },
  { key: 'key2', val: 'val2' },
  { key: 'key3', val: 'val3' }
];

let keyValueMap = keyValueObjArray.reduce((mapAccumulator, obj) => {
  // either one of the following syntax works
  // mapAccumulator[obj.key] = obj.val;
  mapAccumulator.set(obj.key, obj.val);

  return mapAccumulator;
}, new Map());

console.log(keyValueMap);
console.log(keyValueMap.size);
```

What is different between Map And Object?
Previously, before Map was implemented in JavaScript, Object has been used as a Map because of their similar structure.
Depending on your use case, if u need to need to have ordered keys, need to access the size of the map or have frequent addition and removal from the map, a Map is preferable.

Quote from [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object):
Objects are similar to Maps in that both let you set keys to values, retrieve those values, delete keys, and detect whether something is stored at a key. Because of this (and because there were no built-in alternatives), Objects have been used as Maps historically; however, there are important differences that make using a Map preferable in certain cases:

- The keys of an Object are Strings and Symbols, whereas they can be any value for a Map, including functions, objects, and any primitive.
- The keys in Map are ordered while keys added to object are not. Thus, when iterating over it, a Map object returns keys in order of insertion.
- You can get the size of a Map easily with the size property, while the number of properties in an Object must be determined manually.
- A Map is an iterable and can thus be directly iterated, whereas iterating over an Object requires obtaining its keys in some fashion and iterating over them.
- An Object has a prototype, so there are default keys in the map that could collide with your keys if you're not careful. As of ES5 this can be bypassed by using map = Object.create(null), but this is seldom done.
- A Map may perform better in scenarios involving frequent addition and removal of key pairs.

Comment: You are missing an arrow. Change `(mapAccumulator, obj) {...}` for `(mapAccumulator, obj) => {...}`

Answer (score 20):

es2015 version:

```
const myMap = new Map(objArray.map(obj => [ obj.key, obj.val ]));
```

Answer (score 10):

There are better ways to do this as explained by other posters. But if I want to stick to pure JS and ol' fashioned way then here it is:

```
var arr = [
    { key: 'foo', val: 'bar' },
    { key: 'hello', val: 'world' },
    { key: 'hello', val: 'universe' }
];

var map = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var key = arr[i].key;
    var value = arr[i].val;

    if (key in map) {
        map[key].push(value);
    } else {
        map[key] = [value];
    }
}

console.log(map);
```

Comment: is it advised to use reduce method than this method. I feel like using this method. its simple and easy to see everything.

Comment: I love this approach. I think sometimes the simplest code is the best. People are turned off by mutability nowadays, but as long as it's contained, mutability is actually pretty awesome and performant.

Comment: I am using this because IE11 do not permit the one with Lambda

Comment: Thank you for posting the only example with multiple keys that are the same, which is the situation I needed to handle. I also like this because as Anthosh said you can actually see what is going on. My only suggestion for improving this answer would be to show the output

Answer (score 7):

If you want to convert to the new ES6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) do this:

```
var kvArray = [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2']];
var myMap = new Map(kvArray);
```

Why should you use this type of Map? Well that is up to you. Take a look at [this](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/es6-map-vs-object-what-and-when-b80621932373).

Answer (score 5):

This is what I'm doing in TypeScript I have a little utils library where I put things like this

```
export const arrayToHash = (array: any[], id: string = 'id') => 
         array.reduce((obj, item) =>  (obj[item[id]] = item , obj), {})
```

usage:

```
const hash = arrayToHash([{id:1,data:'data'},{id:2,data:'data'}])
```

or if you have a identifier other than 'id'

```
const hash = arrayToHash([{key:1,data:'data'},{key:2,data:'data'}], 'key')
```

Comment: If you want to use an object as a key, you'll have to use Map instead of Object because typescript won't let you use objects as keys

Comment: ```const normalize = (a,f) => a.reduce((m,o)=>(m[o[f]]=o,m),{});```

Answer (score 4):

With `lodash`:

```
const items = [
    { key: 'foo', value: 'bar' },
    { key: 'hello', value: 'world' }
];

const map = _.fromPairs(items.map(item => [item.key, item.val]));

// OR: if you want to index the whole item by key:
// const map = _.fromPairs(items.map(item => [item.key, item]));
```

The lodash `fromPairs` function reminds me about [zip function in Python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip)

Link to [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15)

Answer (score 3):

A small improvement on the `reduce` usage:

```
var arr = [
    { key: 'foo', val: 'bar' },
    { key: 'hello', val: 'world' }
];

var result = arr.reduce((map, obj) => ({
    ...map,
    [obj.key] = obj.val
}), {});

console.log(result);
// { foo: 'bar', hello: 'world' }
```

Comment: Is it faster than the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26265095/450913) answer?

Comment: @orad probably not as it spreads accumulator and creates new object each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

the reduce version seems not work. i go with following.

```
   let map = {};
    items.forEach(v=>{
      map [v.xxx] = v;
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, I prefer not to use any `map` or `reduce` and just stick with simple `for` loop.

```
const array = [
   {key: 'a', value: 'b', redundant: 'aaa'},
   {key: 'x', value: 'y', redundant: 'zzz'}
]

const hash = {};

for (const item of array) {
    hash[item.key] = item;
}

console.log(hash);
```

Comment: I agree with @Yada. Easy to read and straight forward code is much preferable for sanity.

Comment: im a new react MERN developer started 2 years ago and im getting drowned in all this reduce, filter, map stuff..... im learning it though, filter is most confusing to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
 * convert neste object array to Map by object field
 * @param {Array<Object>} array
 * @param {String} fieldName
 * @returns {Map}
*/
function convertNestObjectArrayToMapByField(array, fieldName){
    return new Map(array.map(obj => [obj[fieldName], obj]));
}

/* Example
  const array = [
    { key: 'foo', val: 'bar' },
    { key: 'hello', val: 'world' }
  ];
  let map = convertNestObjectArrayToMapByField(array, 'key');
  console.log(map);
  console.log(map.get('foo'));
  # Console
  Map(2) {
    'foo' => { key: 'foo', val: 'bar' },
    'hello' => { key: 'hello', val: 'world' }
  }
  { key: 'foo', val: 'bar' }
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Using simple Javascript

```
var createMapFromList = function(objectList, property) {
    var objMap = {};
    objectList.forEach(function(obj) {
      objMap[obj[property]] = obj;
    });
    return objMap;
  };
// objectList - the array  ;  property - property as the key
```

Comment: isn't using .map(...) pointless in this example as you don't return anything in it? I would suggest forEach in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I would make it more clear in TypeScript in case someone is interested.

```
interface Person {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
type Result = Map<number, string>

const input: Array<Person> = [
  {
    id: 123,
    name: "naveen"
  },
  {
    id: 345,
    name: "kumar"
  },
];
const convertedToMap: Result = input.reduce(
  (map: Result, person: Person) => {
    map.set(person.id, person.name);
    return map;
  },
  new Map()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
let toHashMap = (a,f) => a.reduce((a,c)=> (a[f(c)]=c,a),{});
```

```js
let arr=[
  {id:123, name:'naveen'}, 
  {id:345, name:"kumar"}
];

let fkey = o => o.id; // function changing object to string (key)

let toHashMap = (a,f) => a.reduce((a,c)=> (a[f(c)]=c,a),{});

console.log( toHashMap(arr,fkey) );

// Adding to prototype is NOT recommented:
//
// Array.prototype.toHashMap = function(f) { return toHashMap(this,f) };
// console.log( arr.toHashMap(fkey) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reusable generic typescript function that'll work for first-level properties of an object and will give you intellisense when calling it. It will also give you **correct types** on the produced map both **for keys and values**.

```
const arrayToMap = <K extends keyof T, T = Object>(
  array: Array<T>,
  mapByKey: K,
  fatalOnConflicts: boolean = false
): Map<T[K], T> => {
  const map = new Map<T[K], T>();
  for (const element of array) {
    const key = element[mapByKey];
    if (fatalOnConflicts && map.has(key)) {
      throw new Error(`Cant convert Array to Map because of duplicate key '${key}' on property '${String(mapByKey)}'`);
    }
    map.set(key, element);
  }

  return map;
};
```

Usage examples

```
type MyType = {
  id: number,
  color: string
}

const array: Array<MyType> = [
  { id: 1, color: "red" },
  { id: 2, color: "blue" },
  { id: 1, color: "green" }
];


//will give a map of type Map<number, MyType> (key "1" will have value {id: 1, color: "green"} - latest value survives)
const map = arrayToMap(array, "id");
//will give a map of type Map<string, MyType>
const map2 = arrayToMap(array, "color");
//will throw an error during runtime for duplicate key '1'
const map3 = arrayToMap(array, "id", true);
//will be recognized as error by vs code and will produce a build error "Argument of type '"non-existent-property"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"id" | "color"'."
const map4 = arrayToMap(array, "non-existent-property");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
var keyValueObjectArray = [
  { key: "foo", val: "bar" },
  { key: "hello", val: "world" },
];

//array
var keyValueArray = keyValueObjectArray.map((elm) => [elm.key, elm.val]);
//console.log(keyValueArray);

//array to map
var keyValueMap = new Map(keyValueArray);
//console.log(keyValueMap);

//map to object
var result = {}
for (const [key, value] of keyValueMap) {
  result[key] = value
}
console.log(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{ foo: 'bar', hello: 'world' }
```

Answer (score -2):

Following is small snippet i've created in javascript to convert array of objects to hash map, indexed by attribute value of object. You can provide a function to evaluate the key of hash map dynamically (run time).

```
function isFunction(func){
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(func) === '[object Function]';
}

/**
 * This function converts an array to hash map
 * @param {String | function} key describes the key to be evaluated in each object to use as key for hasmap
 * @returns Object
 * @Example 
 *      [{id:123, name:'naveen'}, {id:345, name:"kumar"}].toHashMap("id")
        Returns :- Object {123: Object, 345: Object}

        [{id:123, name:'naveen'}, {id:345, name:"kumar"}].toHashMap(function(obj){return obj.id+1})
        Returns :- Object {124: Object, 346: Object}
 */
Array.prototype.toHashMap = function(key){
    var _hashMap = {}, getKey = isFunction(key)?key: function(_obj){return _obj[key];};
    this.forEach(function (obj){
        _hashMap[getKey(obj)] = obj;
    });
    return _hashMap;
};
```

You can find the gist here : https://gist.github.com/naveen-ithappu/c7cd5026f6002131c1fa

Comment: Please, please, please don't recommend extending `Array.prototype`!

Comment: Ahh, I see. I initially thought this was a proposed answer :)

Answer (score -2):

Map the array like this:

```
const items = [
{ key: 'foo', value: 'bar' },
{ key: 'hello', value: 'world' }
];

let [k,v] = items.map(item => [item.key, item.value])   
console.log([k,v]) 

//Output: [ [ 'foo', 'bar' ], [ 'hello', 'world' ] ]
```