# Reducing array of objects to hashmap in JS

Tags: javascript, reduce

Hi I am trying to transform a JSON data type from one format to another:

```
  [ { name: 'CarNo', attributes: {}, children: [], content: '?' },
       { name: 'AccNo', attributes: {}, children: [], content: '?' },
     { name: 'SCS', attributes: {}, children: [], content: '?' }]
```

The target object would be based on the name property and the content property:

```
   {'CarNo': '?', 'AccNo': '?', 'SCS': '?' }
```

I was thinking I could just reduce this but I am failing:

```
        const filteredResponseObj = Object.keys(rawResponseBodyObj).reduce((p,c)=>{
          if( c === 'name' ){
            p[c]=rawResponseBodyObj[c].content;
          }
          return p;
        },{});
```

What am I missing? clearly I have some issues with the reduction...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had the right idea, but here is how to do it:

```
const filteredResponseObj = rawResponseBodyObj.reduce(function(map, obj) {
    map[obj.name] = obj.content;
    return map;
}, {});
```

Using [Convert object array to hash map, indexed by an attribute value of the Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264956/convert-object-array-to-hash-map-indexed-by-an-attribute-value-of-the-object)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with  [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for the object generation.

```js
var array = [{ name: 'CarNo', attributes: {}, children: [], content: '?' }, { name: 'AccNo', attributes: {}, children: [], content: '?' }, { name: 'SCS', attributes: {}, children: [], content: '?' }],
    result = Object.assign(...array.map(o => ({ [o.name]: o.content })));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

With this line `c === 'name'` you are trying to compare an object from the initial array with string `name`. Such comparison will always give `false`

The right way should be as below:

```js
var arr = [ { name: 'CarNo', attributes: {}, children: [], content: '?' },
    { name: 'AccNo', attributes: {}, children: [], content: '?' },
    { name: 'SCS', attributes: {}, children: [], content: '?' }],

    filtered = arr.reduce(function (r, o) {
        if (!r[o.name]) r[o.name] = o['content'];
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(filtered);
```