# JavaScript: Convert array of objects into hashmap

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a set of values in an array where each value has an `ID` and `LABEL`.

Once I have the value array and type console `value[0]` and `value[1]`, the output is:

```
value[0] 
Object {ID: 0, LABEL: turbo}

value[1] 
Object {ID: 1, LABEL: classic}
```

How can I store these values in a hash map like a key-value (ID-LABEL) pair, and store them in a json?

Comment: Learn about what JSON is, understand that all JavaScript objects, including arrays and functions, are morally hash tables, and your question will disappear because it won't even make sense to you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert object array to hash map, indexed by an attribute value of the Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264956/convert-object-array-to-hash-map-indexed-by-an-attribute-value-of-the-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved by calling [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on your array of values (ie `data`), to obtain the required hash map (where `ID` is the key and value is the corresponding `LABEL`):

```js
const data = [
{ID: 0, LABEL: 'turbo'},
{ID: 1, LABEL: 'classic'},
{ID: 7, LABEL: 'unknown'}
];

const hashMap = data.reduce((result, item) => {
  return { ...result, [ item.ID ] : item.LABEL };
}, {});

const hashMapJson = JSON.stringify(hashMap);

console.log('hashMap', hashMap);
console.log('hashMapJson', hashMapJson);
 
/*
More concise syntax:
console.log(data.reduce((result, { ID, LABEL }) => ({ ...result, [ ID ] : LABEL }), {}))
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try (where h={})

```
data.map(x=> h[x.ID]=x.LABEL );
```

```js
const data = [
  {ID: 0, LABEL: 'turbo'},
  {ID: 1, LABEL: 'classic'},
  {ID: 3, LABEL: 'abc'}
];

let h={}
data.map(x=> h[x.ID]=x.LABEL );

console.log(h);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterator over each item in the array, and use the `ID` proeprty as a javascript objects `key` and the `LABEL` as the `value`.

```js
var value = [{ID: 0, LABEL: "turbo"}, {ID: 1, LABEL: "classic"}];

let theNewMap = {};
for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
  theNewMap[value[i].ID] = value[i].LABEL;
}

// theNewMap Should now be a map with 'id' as key, and 'label' as value
console.log(JSON.stringify(theNewMap ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [forEach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp) method.

```
> var hmap = {};
undefined
> var value = [{ID: 0, LABEL: "turbo"}, {ID: 1, LABEL: "classic"}]
undefined
> value.forEach(function(element){
... hmap[element.ID] = element.LABEL;
... });
> hmap
{ '0': 'turbo', '1': 'classic' }
```

or

```
var value = [{ID: 0, LABEL: "turbo"}, {ID: 1, LABEL: "classic"}]
var hmap = {};
value.forEach(function(element){
    hmap[element.ID] = element.LABEL;
});
console.log(hmap);
```