# Initialising an array of objects with the index as key

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to find out how to initialise an array of objects, where each object has the index (i) as its key and 0 as its value. The code below is not working as expected but I can't see why. I'm still quite beginner with Javascript and couldn't find an answer elsewhere.

```
var n = 10;
var sample = [];
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sample.push({i : 0});
```

Comment: {}Use computed property `{[i]: 0}`

Comment: For the computed property documentation see: [MDN Object initializer - Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert object array to hash map, indexed by an attribute value of the Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264956/convert-object-array-to-hash-map-indexed-by-an-attribute-value-of-the-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use this syntax `sample.push({[i]: 0})`;

when you need to access object property which is stored under some variable you should always use **square brackets** no matter you need write to or read from an object

Answer (score 3):

The code below should take care of the job:

```
let n = 10;
let sample = Array.from({length:n}, (_, i) => ({ [i]: 0 }));
```

As pointed by Oleksandr Sakun on his answer, the index is used between brackets in order to evaluate the variable and set as a property of the object.

Answer (score 0):

For a funcitonal approach you can try:

```
const initArray = (n)=>{
  const newArr = new Array(n).fill(0);
  return newArr.map((value, index)=> ({[index]: value}))
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

add square brackets to the index [i] :

```
  var n = 10;
  var sample = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
      sample.push({[i]: 0});
  console.log(sample);
```

Comment: This answer does not address the OP question.

Comment: it initializes and Array with n objects and i as key value. object value is 0. cant see why it shouldnt work for OP.

Comment: expected result is `[{"0":0},{"1":0},{"2":0},{"3":0},{"4":0},{"5":0},{"6":0},{"7":0},{"8":0},{"9":0}]` and this is not the result returned by your answer.

Comment: if this is the case, I have to edit it to sample.push({[i]: 0});