# match between two array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, matching

I'm building an api to add orders for a store,
in the function I receive identity attributes (clientId...) and an array of the order as so:

```
order = [{packageId,quantity},...]
```

I then get the prices of the packages from to DB the get the latest price as so :

```
packagePrice= [{packageId,unitPrice}, ...(all the packages that are needed)]
```

my problem is that how could I reconstruct the `order` array to match each package with its price as so:

```
order=[{packageId, quantity, UnitPrice}, ...( all other packages)]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding the `unitPrice` to the existing `order` array would be:

```
order.forEach(
  v1 => v1.unitPrice = packagePrice.find(
    v2 => v1.packageId === v2.packageId
  )?.unitPrice
);
```

Answer (score 1):

A nested loop

```js
var packageId = 1277;
var quantity = 2;
var unitPrice = 1.00

var order = [{packageId,quantity}]

var packagePrice= [{packageId,unitPrice}]

order.forEach(function(item) {
  item.unitPrice = packagePrice.find(function(item2) {
    return item2.packageId == item.packageId
  }).unitPrice
})

console.log(order)
```

Comment: Why use `map()` if you're going to discard the result of the `map()` operation anyway?

Comment: No reason just was a harmless error.

Comment: The return of your `find()` function is incorrect. You're assigning instead of comparing.

Answer (score 1):

There are more than on way to handle this. From a maintainablility and readability stand point i would do it it in two steps :

1 - Convert the array of package `[{packageid,price}]`, to a map `{packageid:price}` :

This would make it easyer to use elsewere in the code
Here is a way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26265095/8541886

2 - map over the order items

You could use `Array.map()` or a simple `for` loop to add the prices to the order array

Here is how the code would look :

```js
// get the unit prices as a map
const unitPrices = packagePrice.reduce( 
   (prices,pakageprice) => {
      prices[pakageprice.packageId] = pakageprice.unitPrice
      return prices
   },
   {} // initial value for unit prices
)

// add it to the order array
const ordersWithPrices = orders.map( order => {
    order.unitPrice = unitPrices[order.packageId]
    return order
} )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { merge } from "lodash";

var object = [{ b: 2, c: 3 }];
var other = [{ b: 2, e: 5 }];

console.log(merge(object, other));
```

Use Lodash merge that will allow you to merge two arrays into one.

https://codesandbox.io/s/lodash-playground-forked-rjfu80?file=/src/index.js:0-129